# I have interesting issue which first I'm not sure even if it's need to be fix regarding angular route

Tags: angular, routes, usability

I have navigation in the header with:

```
[routerLink]="/base/privatepage"
```

The navigation is working fine and the module is not relaod which is good. Now, this is
page is a form page. It has some field being automatically populated. Now, user may do this:
delete all the populated fields, click save, fail validation with errors for example.
Now, he click on the same header link and the component is not reset, the user is not able
to enjoy from auto populated fields (of course he can click refresh but encourage him to do it
will end up with my services to reconsruct).
Even for page that not doing populate fields, errors can be shown, and user by clicking again
will see the same state.
I don't know really what to do here, all I think of is that I was not expecting to see there errors in the page when click second time.

So, I guess I'm looking for someone that experience the same to say how should we address this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually reload a page/component when you navigate to the same place, you need to tell the router to do so. By default it doesn't because that is generally the preferred option.

```js
@ngModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
 exports: [RouterModule],
 })
```

Comment: forRoot  is in main app routing, in this module I'm loading module lazily. using this config, it will load the whole module for all routes so I can't do this.